# using TakeWhile() to return ranges of values

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using takewhile to categorize a series of values this way :

```
 var Range_1 = Dictionary_Name.TakeWhile (x=> x.Value < 50).toList();
```

The dictionary (String,int) contains values as below:

```
 [Item 1, 10]
 [Item 2, 20]
 [Item 3, 5]
 [Item 4, 3]
 [Item 5, 41]
 ,...
```

The code that I'm using then produce the correct result but when I change the value to like:

```
 var Range_1 = Dictionary_Name.TakeWhile (x=> x.Value < 10).toList();
```

It returns an empty colection.

I would like to know why it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Does it return `null`, or an empty collection?

Comment: Are you sure you don't need `Where` ? Read the difference between TakeWhile and Where....

Comment: I doesn't return anything at all which an empty collection, I'll edit the quetion

Comment: @I4V: Thank you, I think I found the problem :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`TakeWhile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534804.aspx) will stop when it finds the first element that does not match the criteria. So it sees `[Item 1, 10]`, which has a value that is not less than 10, and so it stops iterating.

Maybe you want [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx)`(t => t.Value < 10)` instead, which will simply return all values less than 10.

Comment: Thank you very much Blorgbeard, I'm new too Linq I didn't know that I have to use where instead, the problem is solved and I will accept this answer.

Comment: @Jack I'll add that in a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` there **isn't** any ordering, so the greatest element could be the first, the smallest in the middle, and the random element could be last.

Answer (score 1):

The first element has a Value of 10, and the condition is `(x=> x.Value < 10)`, so it has to return empty set. If you just want to filter Values < 10, use `Where` instead of `TakeWhile`.

Answer (score 0):

`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`, when enumerated, doesn't return its key/value pairs in any particular order. It should be repeatable, providing the dictionary isn't modified between enumerations, but the order is dependent, I believe, in the computed hash value for each key, the order in which values were inserted and the hash bucket in which each item was put.

If you want an ordered collection, look at the following `System.Collections.Generic` classes:

- [`SortedDictionary<K,V>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx)
- [`SortedList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx)
- [`SortedSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx)

Linq can help too, using it's `Join()` method:

```
Dictionary<int,string>     dictionary = GetSomeDictionary() ;
KeyValuePair<int,string>[] matches    = Enumerable.Range(1,50)        // outer (left) set
                                                  .Join( dictionary , // inner (right) set
                                                     x => x         , // outer key selector
                                                     y => y.Key     , // inner key selector
                                                     (x,y) => y       // result selector
                                                  )
                                                  .ToArray()
                                                  ;
```

Or, as @zxspectrum pointed out, use `Where()` instead of `TakeWhile()`.